# Gatsby syncing the table of contents with the page scroll and style the active link

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I've used `data.markdownRemark.tableOfContents` to generate the table of contents of any markdown file, however, it is just HTML, I mean it does not behave like the ToCs that appears on the Gatsby's documentation pages, I want the links in the ToCs to be active and inactive according to the section that currently showing up when the user scrolls to it, exactly like the how the ToCs of the Gatsby's documentation behave.

I made a ton of research and found nothing.

Am I doing something wrong with `data.markdownRemark.tableOfContents`? or is there a way to achieve this that I couldn't find in the documentation? or should I implement this behavior myself using vanilla JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this question on the [Gatsby's GitHub repository](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/22586) and the team told me that this is something we have to implement on our own.

Here is how I implemented it:

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo } from "react"
import { useActiveHash } from "../../reactHooks/use-active-hash"

export default function TableOfContents({ html }) {
  let targetedIds = useMemo(() => {
    var dummyDOM = document.createElement("html")
    dummyDOM.innerHTML = html
    const justAnchors = dummyDOM.querySelectorAll(`a`)

    let val = []
    justAnchors.forEach(a => {
      val.push(a.hash.replace("#", ""))
    })

    return val
  }, [])

  const activeHash = useActiveHash(targetedIds)

  useEffect(() => {
    const ToClinks = document.querySelectorAll(`.ToCs a`)

    ToClinks.forEach(a => {
      a.classList.remove("isActive")
    })

    const activeLink = document.querySelectorAll(
      `.ToCs a[href$="${"/#" + activeHash}"]`
    )

    if (activeLink.length) {
      activeLink[0].classList.add("isActive")
    }
  }, [activeHash])

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Table Of Contents</h2>
      <div className="ToCs" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

The `html` is `data.markdownRemark.tableOfContents`

`use-active-hash.js` file:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

export const useActiveHash = (itemIds, rootMargin = undefined) => {
  const [activeHash, setActiveHash] = useState(``)

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      entries => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            setActiveHash(entry.target.id)
          }
        })
      },
      { rootMargin: rootMargin || `0% 0% -80% 0%` }
    )

    itemIds.forEach(id => {
      observer.observe(document.getElementById(id))
    })

    return () => {
      itemIds.forEach(id => {
        observer.unobserve(document.getElementById(id))
      })
    }
  }, [])

  return activeHash
}
```

[use-active-hash.js source](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/www/src/hooks/use-active-hash.js)

This was my implementation, it simply adds `isActive` class to the table of contents' active link, you can take a look at how the Gatsby's team implemented it [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/www/src/components/docs-table-of-contents.js).